# Debugging an SSR NetworkError in Angular 9 + .NET Core 3.1

Tags: angular, .net-core, server-side-rendering, visual-studio-2022, angular-universal

I have an Angular 9 app with a .NET Core 3.1 API. I realize `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` is obsolete, but we don't have an option to upgrade yet. We've been trying to add dynamic SSR via Angular Universal with limited success. The app builds/runs with `ng run ClientApp:serve-ssr` and the **browser** version loads, but the server version doesn't. We've studied the "gotchas" and fixed one `document` issue by using `isPlatformBrowser(platformId)`. I suspect the latest error is due to a relative URL, probably in an API call...the problem is, Visual Studio 2022's Output Window shows a stack trace (below) of limited usefulness, with no other context:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29\System.Net.WebClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Error: ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:299844:19)
    at Observable._subscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:37830:17)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:285345:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:285331:22)
    at DoOperator.call (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:292738:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:285326:31)
    at scheduleTask (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:171521:32)
    at Observable._subscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:171583:13)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:285345:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\Source\Repos\X\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js:285331:22)
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Source\Repos\X\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\Source\Repos\X\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

The referenced site in **main.js** is the **XmlHttpRequest.send()** call's 'Unsupported protocol' throw:

[image]

So, how can I best discover where the call originates within the server-side Angular app running on the Express server? Can I configure more verbose logging from the .NET side, tweak `angular.json` to add a debugging-related build feature, can I attach a debugger to the Node.js app (I saw debugging options available in the `NodeServicesOptions` object (i.e. `LaunchWithDebugging` and `DebuggingPort`, but how are those used?)? Other approaches?

Comment: I've already considered attempting an online repro, but obviously that's problematic as I can't determine the source of the issue, and it's a huge project. :)